# what is the best way to export data from Filemaker Pro 6 to Sql Server?

Tags: odbc, export, filemaker

I'm migrating/consolidating multiple FMP6 databases to a single C# application backed by SQL Server 2008. the problem I have is how to export the data to a real database (SQL Server) so I can work on data quality and normalisation. Which will be significant, there are a number of repeating fields that need to be normalised into child tables.

As I see it there are a few different options, most of which involve either connecting to to FMP over ODBC and using an intermediate to copy the data across (either custom code or MS Acess linked tables), or, exporting to flat file format (CSV with no header or xml) and either use excel to generate insert statements or write some custom code to load the file.

I'm leaning towards writing some custom code to do the migration (like [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/filemaker_mysql_whitepaper/filemaker_to_mysql_whitepaper01.htm) does, but in C# instead of perl) over ODBC, but I'm concerned about the overhead of writing a migrator that will only be used once (as soon as the new system is up the existing DB's will be archived)...

a few little joyful caveats: in this version of FMP there's only one table per file, and a single column may have multi-value attributes, separated by hex 1D, which is the ASCII group separator, of course!

Does anyone have experience with similar migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past, but using MySQL as the backend. The method I use is to export as csv or merge format and them use the LOAD DATA INFILE statement.

SQL Server may have something similar, maybe this link would help [bulk insert](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-load-text-or-csv-file-data-into-sql-server.html)